# Why the JavaScript function doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

If you click the button, it should have showed, but it doesn't.

Is any wrong here?

I have written many JavaScript files in this way, and tried many ways like changing the position of JavaScript code anywhere. But all the files I wrote don't work

Thanks in advance!

An instance :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Debug</title>
</head>
<style>
    .debug {
         display : none;
    }
</style>
<body>
<div class = "debug">
    <p>Welcome!</p>
</div>
<button class = "show" onclick = "JavaScript : show();">Show</button>
<script type = "text/JavaScript">
    function show() {
        document.querySelector("debug").style.display = "flex";
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks to all of you!

Comment: @VicJordan this question has nothing to do with jQuery's selectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## About [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

> The Document method querySelector() returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector. [...] **The selector is a CSS selector string**.
>
> - [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

You should, therefore, put in your code:

```
document.querySelector(".debug")
```

---

- You can also select HTML elements by their tags, for example, you want to select the first `div`:

  ```
  document.querySelector("div")
  ```

  ```js
  document.querySelector("div").style.color = "lightgreen"
  ```

  ```html
  <div>Hello World</div>
  ```
- Imagine you had your own HTML tag: `<hello>`, then you can select all `hello` elements with:

  ```
  document.querySelector("hello")
  ```

  ```js
  document.querySelector("hello").style.color = "lightblue"
  ```

  ```html
  <hello>Hello World</hello>
  ```

---

### Side note on inline eventListeners

Also in HTML for inline event listener instead of:

```
<button class = "show" onclick = "JavaScript : show();">Show</button>
```

you can simply write:

```
<button class = "show" onclick = "show();">Show</button>
```

It is recommended to use JavaScript to initiate these eventListeners instead of having them inline inside your HTML markup. Use the [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method:

```
document.querySelector(".show").addEventListener('click', show)
                                                    ↑      ↑
                                                  event  function
                                                  type
```

---

### Back to your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Debug</title>
</head>
<style>
    .debug {
        display : none;
    }
</style>
<body>
<div class = "debug">
    <p>Welcome!</p>
</div>
<button class ="show">Show</button>
<script type = "text/JavaScript">
    document.querySelector(".show").addEventListener("click", show)
    function show() {
        document.querySelector(".debug").style.display = "flex";
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### Last thing

Also it's better to keep HTML, JavaScript and CSS all in separate files, for instance:

```
- index.html
- style.css
- script.js
```

And call the CSS and JavaScript files in your HTML file with the [`link`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp) (preferably inside `<head>`) and [`script`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp) (at the bottom of `<body>`) tags:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

And

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: `.querySelector` only returns one Element, not all. That's what `.querySelectorAll` is there for, giving you an array(-like structure) to then iterate or forEach over.

Comment: Of course, you can use `querySelectorAll`, then you will need to unwrap the `NodeList` of `HTMLElement` objects before applying `Array`'s methods. But here OP didn't mention having multiple `.show` elements.

Comment: I know, it's just that you say "you want to select _all_ `div`" instead of "the first".

Answer (score 1):

For class selector you need to add a **dot (.)** e.g. `.debug`

Also, in HTML, you can simply have onclick as `onclick="show();"`

```js
function show() {
  document.querySelector(".debug").style.display = "flex";
}
```

```css
.debug {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="debug">
  <p>Welcome!</p>
</div>
<button class="show" onclick="show();">Show</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

queryselectors requires `.` and `#` for class and ID selector:

```
querySelector(".debug")
```

Answer (score 1):

You were not passing class to querySelector. Set `".debug"` instead of `"debug"`.

Below is working code:

```js
function show() {
  document.querySelector(".debug").style.display = "flex";
}
```

```css
.debug {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="debug">
  <p>Welcome!</p>
</div>
<button class="show" onclick="JavaScript : show();">Show</button>
```